# php desktop not able to connect with MYSQL workbench

Tags: php, mysql-workbench, phpdesktop

I am using MYSQL workbench as a database and PHP to connect to MYSQL workbench while connecting I am getting the following error.

```
Warning: mysqli::__construct(): Server sent charset (255) unknown to the client. Please, report to the developers in C:\Users\phpdesktop\phpdesktop-chrome-57.0-rc-php-7.1.3\www\index.php on line 3
```

and

```
Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2054): Server sent charset unknown to the client. Please, report to the developers in C:\Users\phpdesktop\phpdesktop-chrome-57.0-rc-php-7.1.3\www\index.php on line 3
```

and

```
Warning: mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\Users\phpdesktop\phpdesktop-chrome-57.0-rc-php-7.1.3\www\index.php on line 13
```

Following is my code

```
<?php $conn = new mysqli('localhost' , 'root' , '' , 'database_name'); 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

// insert username into the database table

$Username = $conn->real_escape_string(stripslashes(trim($_POST['Username'])));

$conn->query("INSERT INTO table_name (Username) VALUES ('$Username'");

}

?>

<!DOCTYPE>

<html>

<head>

<meta = charset=UTF-8>
<title>Insert Username</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="username" method="post" action="">
<p>Username<br>

<input type="text" name="Username">
</p>
<p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</p>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Above is my code that I am using to insert data to MySQL workbench database but continuously getting above mentioned error.

Comment: Terminology note: MySQL workbench is a **client** application. I doubt you want to connect to that. In this code, PHP is acting as the client. You likely want to connect to the MySQL **server**. It's a good idea to understand the purpose and role of the different tools and technologies you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add following code to `/etc/mysql/conf.d` and restart mysqld:

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8


[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
character-set-server = utf8
```